# PostgreSQL trigger not firing. Can you see anything wrong?

Tags: postgresql

Wrote this trigger 5-6 months ago, and it ran fine on the db I deployed it to. Just took it off the shelf, and pretty much dropped it on the same database which lives on a different box. Sucker isn't executing anymore.

Essentially, this trigger just copies the "before" row to an audit table. The audit table lives in a different db on the same server, and I link it back to the source database as a FOREIGN Table:

Audit db:

```
CREATE TABLE next_gen_permissions_change
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  authorizable_type character varying(64),
  authorizable_id integer,
  grantee_id integer,
  grantee_type character varying(255),
  capability_id integer NOT NULL,
  permission integer DEFAULT 0,
  event_time timestamp without time zone,
  event_type character varying(10)
)
GRANT ALL ON TABLE next_gen_permissions_change TO foo;
```

I create the foreign table in the "source" database:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
CREATE SERVER myserver FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw OPTIONS (host 'localhost', dbname 'audit', port '5432');
CREATE USER MAPPING FOR foo SERVER myserver OPTIONS (user 'foo', password 'secret');

CREATE foreign TABLE next_gen_permissions_change
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  authorizable_type character varying(64),
  authorizable_id integer,
  grantee_id integer,
  grantee_type character varying(255),
  capability_id integer NOT NULL,
  permission integer DEFAULT 0,
  event_time timestamp without time zone,
  event_type character varying(10))
SERVER myserver;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE next_gen_permissions_change TO foo;
```

When I INSERT rows into source.next_gen_permissions_change, I see them show up in audit.next_gen_permissions_change...so I got that going for me.

Here's the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit_permissions()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    trigger_event_time timestamp;
BEGIN
    trigger_event_time := now();

    IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    INSERT INTO next_gen_permissions_change(
            id, 
            authorizable_type, 
            authorizable_id, 
            grantee_id, 
            grantee_type, 
            capability_id, 
            permission, 
            event_time, 
            event_type)
        VALUES (NEW.id,
            NEW.authorizable_type, 
            NEW.authorizable_id, 
            NEW.grantee_id, 
            NEW.grantee_type, 
            NEW.capability_id, 
            NEW.permission, 
            trigger_event_time, 
            'insert');
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSIF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            INSERT INTO next_gen_permissions_change(
            id, 
            authorizable_type, 
            authorizable_id, 
            grantee_id, 
            grantee_type, 
            capability_id, 
            permission, 
            event_time, 
            event_type)
        VALUES (OLD.id,
            OLD.authorizable_type, 
            OLD.authorizable_id, 
            OLD.grantee_id, 
            OLD.grantee_type, 
            OLD.capability_id, 
            OLD.permission, 
            trigger_event_time, 
            'delete');
            RETURN OLD;
    END IF;

    RETURN null;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

And now, I'm adding the function as a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER next_gen_permissions_audit
AFTER INSERT OR DELETE
ON next_gen_permissions
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit_permissions();
```

No errors, all seems well:

[image]

As you can see, I added RAISE NOTICE as well, so I could hopefully see this sucker executing in pgadmin.

Here are all of the properties of the trigger (parent window) and function (child window embedded inside the parent):

[image]

WHEN executing something like

```
UPDATE next_gen_permissions SET f1=f1
```

...I don't see anything in the messages.

Also,

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE UPDATE next_gen_permissions SET f1=f1
```

doesn't return anything interesting:

[image]

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? I'm not getting any error messages, and when I look at the logs, the UPDATE goes right through without ANY mention that the trigger is getting fired.

Thanks much.

Comment: Your trigger is defined as `AFTER INSERT OR DELETE` it will never fire for an `UPDATE` statement

Comment: Thanks, @a_horse_with_no_name I dropped & re-created the trigger with BEFORE, and don't see a change: CREATE TRIGGER next_gen_permissions_audit
  BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE
  ON public.next_gen_permissions
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.audit_permissions();

Comment: It's not about before or after. A trigger defined as `INSERT OR DELETE` will never fire for an `UPDATE` statement. You need `INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE`

Comment: Bingo. That did it. I misunderstood you. Thanks very much.